# Azure Data Factory SSIS Integration Runtime SSISDB not showing in location dropdown

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-factory

on Azure Data Factory (ADF) we have a SSISDB integration runtime (IR). We want to connect to Azure SQL cloud server / database to run SSIS packages from ADF. SSISDB already exists on this server. All about IR looks OK, its running, VNET/Subnet tests are green, IR test connection to Server endpoint is green. VNet injection method: Standard.

However, when creating a pipeline on ADF, activity "Execute SSIS PAckage", in section "Settings" there is a dropdown for Package location. In this dropdown, the option "SSISDB" is missing.
This is how it should look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxExv.png)
But this "SSISDB" is missing.

Already tried Self-Hosted Integration Runtime as a proxy, all green lights for all tests, but still SSISDB missing in dropdown.

I tried the same on synapse, with same results.

Could anyone give some advise on this? How can I get the "SSISDB" option into the location dropdown?

Comment: Did you provision SSIS-IR with an SSIS catalog?

Comment: No, I would like to use an existing SSISDB

Comment: While provisioning SSIS-IR did you create with existing SSISDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would like to use an existing SSISDB in SSIS Integration Runtime.

But as per [Prerequisites of Create an Azure-SSIS integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime#prerequisites)

> Confirm that your database server does not have an SSISDB instance already. The provisioning of an Azure-SSIS IR does not support using an existing SSISDB instance.

This might be the reason you are not able to view SSISDB option in the Package location dropdown.

Follow [provision an Azure-SSIS IR using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime-portal) this document to set up an Azure-SSIS IR.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to delete the SSISDB under Integration service catalogues from SSMS.  Then retry provisioning SSIS IR from Azure Portal (ADF).